# Python ssh2 connection with linux

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I'm trying to execute some commands from my laptop (local), to my dedicated machine using ssh2 and Python.
When I try to show all files with `ls` command I'm always receiving this message.

```
>     Linux v2 5.2.13-gs-md #5213 SMP Sun Sep 8 01:47:29 CEST 2019 x86_64
>     
>     The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
>     the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
>     individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
>     
>     Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
>     permitted by applicable law.
```

And this is my code.

```
import socket, time
from ssh2.session import Session

host = '11.22.33.44.55'
user = 'root'
password = 'itssecret'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host, 2244))

session = Session()
session.handshake(sock)
session.userauth_password(user, password)

channel = session.open_session()
channel.shell()

channel.write("cd /")
channel.write("ls")
time.sleep(1)


size, data = channel.read()
print(data.decode())

channel.close()
```

Even when I try only `cd /` I have same output.

Comment: That's the contents of the `/etc/issue` file that's displayed whenever you login to the server.

Comment: I have tried connecting to my Linux machine via SSH using `paramiko`, no such problem occurred.  http://www.paramiko.org/

Comment: Don't you see that if you do an interactive ssh to ths server?

Comment: Paramiko probably isn't doing an interactive login, `ssh2.session` is.

Comment: So Actually I'm logged in but I can't do anything on it?

Comment: `channel.write("cd /")` - the `cd` may happen in a new subshell, and be lost when the subshell exits. If `ssh2.session` has a `change_directory` command, you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
channel.write("cd /")
channel.write("ls")
```

This just writes `cd /` and `ls` to the session.  If you logged into a SSH session and just hit `cd /ls` very likely nothing would happen till you hit enter, and then you'd not do the two commands you want.

You can send newlines, but better is to use the library's built in system to send commands, and also verify that the command finishes, and the connection itself closes down cleanly:

```
channel.execute('cd /')
channel.execute('ls')
channel.wait_eof()
channel.close()
channel.wait_closed()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I get a ssh2.exceptions.BadUseError on the second execute() command.